# How to export a dynamic web project as .exe

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, deployment, web-deployment

I have a dynamic web project in eclipse mars.How to give that to others as a .exe or any other format so that they can open the HTML page directly without changing the path of the source files.Thanks in advance

Comment: In which language?? is it java or php or some other framework?

Comment: if you are creating a dynamic web project to run on tomcat, then you can export it to .war using File --> Export

Comment: @ShalinPatel It is developed using javascript

Comment: Is it javascript and html only??

Comment: @printfmyname It is not runnig on a tomcat server it just opens a html page and process the data

Comment: @ShalinPatel Yes that's it

Comment: You can just copy past that folder to remot pc and click on index page and it will work just fine..

Comment: @ShalinPatel Thank you I'll give a try on that